# cron tab not working with virtual env django

Tags: python, django, cron

I am using python django community ami from bitnami and i am not able to execute python script in cron via virtual env

Directly executing script in terminal works e.g.

/path/to/env/bin/python /path/to/script.py (works)

crontab (non sudo)

*/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python /path/to/script.py (works)

/path/to/env/bin/python /path/to/script.py >> /tmp/log.out 2>&1 (not working)*

**"Cannot locate wrapped file"**

Comment: try django-crontab

Comment: i have, no luck

Answer (score 0):

One possible error is forgetting to enable the virtual environment.

I'd have expected to see a crontab line along the lines of the following (taken from [django-cron](http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)) which includes a call to '.../bin/activate'.

```
> crontab -e */5 * * * * source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && source /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/bin/activate && python /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/src/manage.py runcrons > /home/ubuntu/cronjob.log
```